# Add To Homescreen not working

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, service-worker-events

My website is hosted over https.
It have a manifest.json file, service-worker.js and SW register code. But I'm not seeing the the add to Homescreen popup From mobile phones. Why?
Here is index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html public "display of affection from creativejs">
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="uft-8" /> <meta name="theme-color" content="#536878" />  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <title>Fireworks!</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"> </head> 
<body> 
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</body>
<script> 
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log("Will service worker register?");
  
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(reg){
    console.log("Yes it did."); 
  }).catch(function(err) { 
    console.log("No it didn't. This happened: ", err) 
  }); 
}
</script>
</html>
```

[Live demo](https://sslclive.github.io)

Comment: Have you looked at the console output? Because i get `TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.` when i visit [your site](https://sslclive.github.io/).

Comment: @Olian04 what can be is reason? I haven't added link to any other web page, so, where is error 404 getting?

Comment: You are trying to fetch `service-worker.js` and fail at it.

Comment: What can be the reason for fail?

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: @Olian04 it yes it is. If not, then if you visit https://sslclive.github.io/service-worker.js, then you could see an error 404 page.

Comment: That is true. Have you visited that address? Because it does return 404.

Comment: @Olian04 I have added that file. But still not working.

Comment: Take a look at the [Google Chrome samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker/basic)

Comment: @Jishnuraj,you might want to read [this](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist).  My guess is the start_url is not pointing to the right path.  My start_url is "./index.html" and its working

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902104/914033 might help you

Answer (score 0):

You must activate service worker. Simple registration won't do.

First see if your browser supports service workers - http://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker

Another important thing is that you have to keep service worker code in separate file. You cannot have it inline.

Service worker must be served only over HTTPS. For testing purposes, it will work on localhost as well.

Include main.js file in your HTML and call service worker from that file. Open page once to install service worker, then close so that it can be applied and open it again in order to activate it.

main.js file

```
// Call service worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
  .register('/sw.js', {
    scope: './'
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Service worker registered!');
  })
  .catch(function(event) {
    console.log('Error:', event);
  });
}
```

sw.js file (must be in root folder because of the scope)

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('Installing Service Worker...', event);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activating Service Worker...', event);
  return self.clients.claim();
});
```

Comment: Another important thing is that you have to keep service worker code in separate file. You cannot have it inline. I will update the answer.