# PWA debug chrome "add to homescreen" button not doing anything

Tags: json, debugging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to add the "add to Homescreen" prompt function to my website. Now I've read the google developer articles and I have everything set up.

Now, If I try to manually add my page to the homescreen with the button "Add to homecreen" in the Chrome devtools > Application > Manifest , nothing is happening. A few times the console showed an error, but after fixing it nothing happens. I don't get the [Add to shelf](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps) banner, but I don't get an error displayed in the console. Lighthouse doesn't show any error either. In fact, lighthouse shows a score of 92 in pwa.

Is this now meaning that everything is working? Is there an other debug function I've overseen?

Edit: If I press the button and than reload the page, after I press reload and the page is acctually loaded, the console displays:

> Site cannot be installed: the page has requested the banner prompt be cancelled

Comment: do you have the web app manifest file in place? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Comment: At least you have the "add to homescreen" appearing in your dev tools, for me it has disappeared in the last week or so, with no clue as to why or how to get it back.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue: Chrome Dev Tools Add to Homescreen was not working on ANY PWA. After days struggling trying to figure out where the problem was I finally found that Chrome main menu has an option to install the app, and that option is working fine. So you don't need to use Chrome Dev Tools option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in localhost, try http://localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.

I don't know why, but I have the same issue when using 127.0.0.1.
After changing to localhost, it works correctly.